Vlookup not found value
I have this data in sheet that i called transaction

Then i have other sheet that called Event Data

THen in Row A17 . I want to show product that bought in same day
MY Goal is getting transaction data (product_name) from transaction sheets.
Here is what i do so far
=VLOOKUP('Event Data'!B2;transaction!A$2:E$2215;4)

The data is not showing as expected

How can i fix it ?
My expected result is something like this
Name         Qty
Product 1     6
Product 2     1

There is two col, Product name and qty

Where does quantity of 4 comes from for PRODUCT 1 if there are 6 rows in transactions sheet with date 2023-01-02 ?

@user11222393 my bad. I've corrected the question

If you don't have HSTACK() or MAP() then use the following, =LET(_a; FILTER(C2:C9;E2:E9=C12); _b; UNIQUE(_a); CHOOSE({1;2}; _b; COUNTIFS(C2:C9;_b;E2:E9;C12)))

VLOOKUP will return only one value. Use FILTER to return multiple values from column:
FILTER(C2:C9,E2:E9=C12)

Wrap it with UNIQUE to get unique values =UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C9,E2:E9=C12)):

Now use this result as helper column in COUNTIF formula or use something like this to spill whole result at once
=LET(a,FILTER(C2:C9,E2:E9=C12),b,UNIQUE(a),c,MAP(b,LAMBDA(z,SUM(1*(z=a)))),HSTACK(b,c))
Result:

Adapt ranges to yours.
EDIT:
For older Excel versions 2 formulas could be used:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C9,E2:E9=C12)) in A14
=SUM(1*(FILTER($C$2:$C$9,$E$2:$E$9=$C$12)=A14)) in B14 and dragged down.
Result:


You just made it look so easy! Still getting used to the MAP function

Hi thanks, now i can get the unique data . But when i try to implement latest formula from your answer =LET(a,FILTER(C2:C2215,E2:C2215=H4),b,UNIQUE(a),c,MAP(b,LAMBDA(z,SUM(1*(z=a)))),HSTACK(b,c)). I get this The first argument of LET must be a valid name.

@Boby it looks like your separator is ; instead of ,. Try =LET(a;FILTER(C2:C2215;E2:C2215=H4);b;UNIQUE(a);c;MAP(b;LAMBDA(z;SUM(1*(z=a))));HSTACK(b;c))

awesome, the error is gone now, i get this invalid name error. But I will accept your answer !

@Excellor I think i facing problem with this =LET(a;FILTER(transaction!C2:C2215;transaction!E2:E2215>=B6);b;UNIQUE(a);c;MAP(b;LAMBDA(z;SUM(1*(z=a))));HSTACK(b;c))
I get #NAME? in my field
when i change it to =LET(a;FILTER(transaction!C2:C2215;transaction!E2:E2215>=B6);b;UNIQUE(a);c;UNIQUE(a);HSTACK(b;c)) there is no error

It is possible that you are using older version of Excel and function MAP doesn't exist. You could try simply start writing formula =MAP and see if it offers autocomplete

ah there is no MAP :(

Does UNIQUE formula work in your Excel?

Yes, the UNIQUE formula is working brilliantly

I believe HSTACK will also not work if there are no MAP

well , HSTACK is exist

hi @Excellor, i tried your formula above. I can get the product, but not the product count

like this =LET(a;FILTER(transaction!C2:C2215;transaction!E2:E2215>=B6);b;UNIQUE(a);c;COUNTIFS($AB$3:$AB$9;b;transaction!E2:E2215;">=B6");c)?
If yes its returning #VALUE!
I wonder what $AB$3:$AB$9 do?

Oh wow, i just copied something wrong, this should fix it: =LET(a;FILTER(transaction!C2:C2215;transaction!E2:E2215>=B6);b;UNIQUE(a);c;countifs(transaction!C2:C2215;b;transaction!E2:E2215;">=B6");HSTACK(b;c)) where C2:C2215 is your list of products, and E2:E2215 is the list of dates.

the count part returning 0, i'm still trying

@Boby found the error, use ">="&B6 instead of ">=B6" or just B6 if you want only B6, not sure where that came in.

Hi @Excellor,  well i can see the product count now. But in the first row, product name is empty, but its showing the product count. Btw, you can update your question tho

@Boby it's User's answer, so I can only propose an edit, are you still using HSTACK(b,c)?

Try this:
=INDEX(transaction!A$2:E$2215, MATCH('Event Data'!B2,transaction!E$2:E$2215,0),4)

Taking in consideration that Event Data!B2 is the date you're searching, and Column E contains the dates, and whatever output you want is in column 4 of the transaction sheet.
This however will only find one value, next step is a bit more complicated.

Source
IFERROR(INDEX(return_range, SMALL(IF(lookup_value = lookup_range , ROW(lookup_range) - MIN(ROW(lookup_range ))+1,""), ROW() - n)),"")

Where:
n is the row number of the first formula cell minus 1.
Now copy the formula down a few steps, make sure to use the CSE though.
Nextup, counting all your products;
You should have something like this by now:
|A  |B  |
|---|---|
|Product 1|BLANK|
|Product 2|BLANK|

In the empty cells in row B (or wherever you want it) use:
=COUNTIFS(Transaction!E2:E225,Event Data!B2,Transaction!C2:C225,A1:A2)

Transaction!E2:E225 should be the range of dates, Event Data!B2 the date you're looking for;
Transaction!C2:C225 are all the products, and A1 is the cell where you put the formula above in (that now produces Product 1);
Drag down as much as needed.

Just a general tip: try to use Tablemark down to show your data, include headers or even the columns, so we can adjust the formula to your actual range. Now it's a bit guessing, based on the formula you gave.
Let me know if it works!
